# Why is there a war in "Fireball" and "Fireball Charming"?

Tags: fireball

I know that there isn't any story in the series, but they do sometimes get into details about the setting (Merkur Era 48,650-48,794). Was there any reason given for the ongoing (very long) war with humanity that is constantly raging outside the manor? Or anything that can be gleaned from interviews with writer/director Wataru Arakawa?

Answer (score 3):

There's some explanation in the Japanese Wikipedia, but the portion is unsourced, and we can't tell if this is backed by any official stuff. Quoted and translated below.

> On a planet which may or may not be Earth, where dolphins, monkeys, birds and other wildlife and natural environment has already vanished, humans have let robots run the government. However, the robots soon turned to aristocracy, to which humans resisted; and now, the war between the human military and robot aristocrats has been going on for 20000 years.